# Insertion of element in the array-

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, insert, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm not so good with C so please help me in this project where I want the user to pick what operation he wants to perform, where I just completed the insertion part of it and here the code is giving the garbage values after the insertion. This is my code so far-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n, opt, i, insOpt, pos, newEle;
    printf("Enter the number of elements you want to store in the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int* arr = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter all %d elements you want to store in the array: ", n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    options:
    printf("Enter the operation you want to perfrom: \n 1. Insertion \n 2. Deletion \n 3. Traversing \n 4. Searching \n 5. Sorting \n 6.Reverse of array \n");
    scanf("%d", &opt);
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 1:
        n++;
        int* newArr=(int*) realloc(arr, n*sizeof(int));
        for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
            newArr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        free(arr);
        arr = newArr;
        printf("Pick where you want to insert: \n 1. Beginning \n 2. Middle \n 3. End \n 4. Position");
        scanf("%d", &insOpt);
        switch (insOpt)
        {
        case 1:
            pos=0;
            break;
        case 2:
            //
            break;
        case 3:
            pos=n;
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Enter the position: ");
            scanf("%d", &pos);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Please pick between 1 to 4: ");
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter the element: ");
        scanf("%d", &newEle);
        for(i=n-1; i>=pos-1; i--){
            arr[i]=arr[i-1];
        }
        arr[pos-1] = newEle;
        printf("Array after insertion: ");
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        }
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I try to insert the element at the beginning it gives me some random values after 8-

> Array after insertion: 8 1512474568 5 1571285629 1432712575 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters this code snippet

```
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    free(arr);
```

does not make sense. The reallocated array already contains existent elements and the pointer `arr` in this case is invalid. So remove this code snippet.

If the user selected the end position then the value of `pos` shall be `n - 1` instead of `n`. on the other hand, if the user selected the position in the beginning of the array then `pos` shall be equal to 0.

In this case the following for loop will look like

```
    for ( i=n-1; i != pos; i--){
        arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    }
    arr[pos] = newEle;
```

Comment: I saw a video about realloc(), maybe I got confused! Thank You for helping, I removed that code and it is working fine! :)